# Use ResultSet for another query

Tags: java, sql, subquery, resultset

I'd like to know if its possible to use a filled ResultSet in a second query. 
I'm thinking about something thats looking like a subquery.

```
SELECT t.id, t.name FROM table t, (
    SELECT * FROM table2
    )
t2
WHERE t.id = t2.id;
```

In SQL-Logic it would look something like this. I would like to use my ResultSet like the inner part of this query.

Comment: Still no idea how to do this in java with a resultSet

Comment: I think the answer is that you can do this in SQL.  If you return the results back to Java, you either need to construct another query or store them in a temporary table in the database.

Comment: Yeah, i had this idea as well. But this feels a bit dirty in my opinion.

Comment: What's stopping you from running the query as it is? Why would you fetch the first resultset if you know that you want to use it later on?

Comment: I need both, the first and the second result set. Since my first actual query takes about 30 seconds to finish, it would be a waste of time to run this query again within another query.

Comment: What's stopping you from running a single query and extracting `t.id`, `t.name` and `t2.*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only use id from your java resultset, you can loop on you resultset to fecth ids and concatene them within your query string, smth like:

```
String query = "SELECT t.id, t.name FROM table t where t.id IN (";
while(rs.next()) {
  query += rs.getInt("id") + ",";
}
query += ")";
```

or better with a parametrized query

Comment: This was a bit difficult to use in my program, but i figured out how it could work. Thanks.